# Rating screen using LWUIT

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I want to create a MIDlet from where I call the class.In the class there is an Image Array which contain 10 images and default ration is 0.Now I want to know how to create the class when the MIDlet call the class suppose `iRating=new Rating(3)`,where Rating is the class name.when I `show()` the form at that moment only 3 image will be highlighted rest are not,if I put 4 then 4 image will highlighted.Please help me how to do
the output will be as follow.
when we click the 3rd star then first three star will be highlighted rest are not.please suggest me how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a checkbox or toggle button (checkbox with `setToggle(true)`) and set the images appropriately. To place 5 of these just add them all into a horizontal layout container.